# Responsive square pseudo element that won't overflow parent

Tags: html, css

Basically I want a child element to use it's parent dimensions to become a square, but it can't overflow so it needs to use the lowest value between height/width.

I know in practice there's no math.min in css, but maybe this can be achieve using a combination of flexbox or some other displays?

In the end what I'm trying to achieve is a responsive "loading spinner" class that works on any element only using css and without needing to add anything but a class.

This fiddle exemplifies my issues : http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/adfnc5tk/40/

```css
/*Spinner with overlay and no mouse events*/
@keyframes spinner {
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.loading::before {
    position:absolute;
    content : '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.loading::after {
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: -12.5%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #07d;
    border-bottom-color: #07d;
    animation: spinner 1s ease infinite;
    z-index: 3;
    padding-top: calc(12.5% - .5em);
    border-width: .5em;
    padding-bottom: calc(12.5% - .5em);
}
.loading.loading-sm::after {
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: -12.5%;
    margin-left: -12.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #07d;
    border-bottom-color: #07d;
    animation: spinner 1s ease infinite;
    z-index: 3;
    padding-top: calc(12.5% - .1em);
    border-width: .1em;
    padding-bottom: calc(12.5% - .1em);
}
.loading {
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: wait;
}

.body {
  text-align:center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding : 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <h1 class="loading">
    If you increase this width too much it overflows, since the sizing is based on width
  </h1>
  <h3>
    But if you reduce the width too much it gets ugly :(
  </h3>
  <button style="font-size:2rem;width:200px;margin:1rem" class="loading loading-sm">
Button
</button>
  <div class="inner-div loading">
    This fixed element doesn't work either
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm quite a beginner in css, the above code is mix of several online examples so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: No...you'd need JS for that.

Comment: Share html as well

Comment: How about using media queries

Comment: @Viira well if there were media queries for elements size...